# How can i use sqlbrite and RxJava 1.x in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, rx-java, sqlbrite

How can i use these given below libraries in eclipse. No jar file is found when i extract these zip files. Are these can only be used with android studio ?

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

https://github.com/square/sqlbrite

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Ivy or Gradle plugins in Eclipse and use their dependency management capabilities in your project. They will download all necessary files.

Comment: why someone has given me -1 even though if it is so basic question.  I will put bounty on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variants:

1. Clone and build jars yourself -> attach to the project.
2. Go to maven central and download jars: [RxJava](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22rxjava%22), [SqlBrite](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22sqlbrite%22).
3. Switch to Gradle + Android Studio or use Maven/Ivy in Eclipse or other IDE.

Comment: Thanks Artem, your answers gets me out of jungle.

Answer (score 0):

I use Android Studio. I add the following to the dependencies in module build.gradle, then like @akarnokd said, the IDE downloads it automatically.

compile 'com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:0.2.1'